# Как правильно нарисовать график с гистограмами на языке R?

Tags: r

Забегая наперед хочу сказать что данное задание учебное, поэтому не обессудьте. Стоит задача построить график нормального распределения. На этом графике должно быть около 100000 попыток замеров и сам график. Попытки должны отображаться в виде гистограммы. Соответственно будет очень много столбиков, поверх которых должна идти линия распределения. Вот нашел график без гистограммы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С виду то что нужно, но не хватает еще гистограммы. Далее нашел формулы
плотности и функции распределения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код для отрисовки:

```
xseq<-seq(-4,4,.01)
y<-2*xseq + rnorm(length(xseq),0,5.5)
hist(y, prob=TRUE, ylim=c(0,.06), breaks=20)
curve(dnorm(x, mean(y), sd(y)), add=TRUE, col="darkblue", lwd=2)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(xseq, cumulative , col="red",type="l",lwd=2, cex=2, cex.axis=.8)
```

И вот тот ужас который получился:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И соответственно мои проблемы:

1. Как добавить больше столбиков, потому что сейчас их больше 20 где-то, а нужно 100000.
2. Как починить маркировку осей графика, а то там что-то не очень понятное происходит.

И главный вопрос- я вообще правильно выполняю поставленную задачу, или есть способ получше?

Comment: Количество столбиков параметр `break=20`, судя по всему. Но 100000 столбцов будет полная ерунда. Нужно разделять на интервалы и считать количество исходов в каждом из них.

Comment: @Эникейщик, да я попробовал с 100к и получился трэш полный)) что имеется в виду - разбить на интервалы?

Comment: вы используете три функции, рисующие три разных картинки (включающих оси координат, графики, надписи) на одном холсте. каждая из них русует в собственном стиле. отсюда вся эта чехарда с осями и надписями. да, наверняка можно отыскать у этих функций параметры, отключающие рисвоание осей и надписей. так, чтобы две из функций рисовали только свои графики, а оси и надписи рисовала только одна из них. но есть и другой путь — использовать «комбайн». наиболее популярный из них содержится в пакете *ggplot2*.

Comment: что такое гистограмма, для чего она служит, и по каким принципам строится — можно прочитать, например, в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)). гистограмма, в которой отрисовывается **каждое** наблюдение — это уже, собственно, и не гистограмма, а просто «зашрихтованный график функции».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мое решение в `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x = sort(rnorm(1e5)),
       cumulative = cumsum(abs(x)/sum(abs(x)))/2.5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 500)+
  geom_density(color = "red")+
  geom_line(aes(y = cumulative), color = "navy")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2.5, name = "cumulative density"))
```

Значение 2.5 взял на глаз.
[image: результат]

Comment: а что вообще вместо 2,5 брать нужно? просто мне кроме этого значения смущает не совсем плавная синяя линия

Comment: А она и не будет плавной, если это реальные данные. Если мы берем абстрактное нормальное распределение, тогда линяя будет плавнее.

2.5 = 1/0.4, это число исключительно для выравнивания правой и левой шкалы.